# Polymorphic binary search tree type mismatch error

Tags: java, polymorphism, binary-search-tree, type-mismatch

I am making a polymorphic binary search tree for an assignment consisting of NonEmptyTree and EmptyTree objects. Each NonEmptyTree has a comparable key and a value associated to it (as well as a right and left Tree objects).

I am writing a lookup method that takes a key object and returns the value associated with it.

NonEmptyTree:

```
package tree;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NonEmptyTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Tree<K, V> {

    private K key;
    private V value;
    private Tree left, right;

    public NonEmptyTree(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            left = right = EmptyTree.getInstance();//Singleton class
    }

    public V lookup(K keyToLookFor) throws NullPointerException{
        if (keyToLookFor.compareTo(key) > 0)
            return right.lookup(keyToLookFor);
        else if (keyToLookFor.compareTo(key) < 0)
            return left.lookup(keyToLookFor);
        else
            return value;
    }
}
```

EmptyTree:

```
    public V lookup(K keyToLookFor) {
        return null;
    }
```

when I try to return right.lookup or left.lookup, eclipse gives a type mismatch error and asks me to cast it to type V and I have no idea why. We are not allowed to use casting in this project so I could really use some help

Comment: Nit: you are checking `if (keyToLookFor.compareTo(key) > 0)` in two of your conditionals, I suspect you mean `<` in one of them.

Comment: Please can you provide more of your class, e.g. the declarations of `left` and `right`.

Comment: Those are all the relevant parts of the class... The Tree interface declares that lookup returns type V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restrict the types of the left and right members:

```
private Tree<K,V> left, right;
```

This way the calls to left.lookup and right.lookup will return the same V as the containing class.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't `@SuppressWarnings` unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: This was a premade skeleton written by my proffesor, that was already coded in "to ensure that the code will not give warnings due to issues with the way that generics are implemented in Java."